# Problem with the truecrypt command prompt command

Tags: c#, command, truecrypt

In C# project I am Accessing true crypt functionality via command prompt command.I have the following task to do.

```
1 Creating a true crypt volume(Encrypted container)
2,Mount the volume with some drive letter
3,Copy To and delete from the mounted drive
4,Dismount the drive
```

I know how to execute command prompt command from C#.And task 2-4 are done.But i am really stuck with the First point.That is, i am unable to find the command for creating true crypt volume.If any body help me with the command prompt command to create a true crypt volume with specific size and password it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,I found that truecrypt volume creation command is only works on linux.Not in windows.So my command was not working

Comment: This may be a long shot,  (and it's from a while ago, so you may not remember), did you get around it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This page mentions a format command line option: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage
Then again this page mentions a -c or --create switch: http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/truecrypt

I havent tried it myself

Comment: I saw the link but i just couldn't go with the command for creating volume that is described in your second link